# PermissionEvaluator targetDomainObject is always null when checking hasPermission

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest, spring-el

I am developing a Spring Data Rest project, and want to check for user permission when he creates or updates a resource

Here's my laptop class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Laptop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String model;

    @Column
    private Long userId;

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        AppUser appUser = (AppUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        userId = appUser.getId();
    }

}
```

Now what I want to do, is to check before user updates the laptop, to make sure that he's updating his laptop and not other's.

Here's my LaptopRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "content")
public interface LaptopRepository extends CrudRepository<Laptop, Long> {

    @Override
    //@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#entity, 'CREATE')")
    @PreAuthorize("#entity.userId == principal.id")
    <S extends Laptop> S save(S entity);

}
```

And here's the PermissionEvaluator's method

```
@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                             Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
    return true;
}
```

Now the point is

- How do I distinguish between `POST` and `PUT` methods?
- If I change my `@PreAuthorize` to just pass the entity to the `hasPermission` method to just test, it always gets passes as `null`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the guides

```
import org.springframework.security.access.method.P;

...

@PreAuthorize("#c.name == authentication.name")
public void doSomething(@P("c") Contact contact);


import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

...

@PreAuthorize("#n == authentication.name")
Contact findContactByName(@Param("n") String name);
```

Adding any of the annotations resolved the problem with null object, and I can distinguish between PUT and POST checking if target's id is null or not